# Text-only 'open file' dialog in terminal without X (similar to Midnight Commander) in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, console, dialog

I need to add 'browse for file' dialog to my console app in Python 3. There's no way to use Tk or any other X applications. I am looking for text-only solutions, similar to the Midnight Commander (mc) dialogs and panels.

Answer (score 1):

I would go to https://pythondialog.sourceforge.io/doc/ This is a system that will give you MC style dialogs and is a clone of the old dialog shell tool.